# What is the MaterialConverterPrism Extension for autodesk-forgeviewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

What kind of design is autodesk-forgeviewer's MaterialConverterPrism Extension used for in Revit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I would like to know is what kind of materials, such as textures, material types, etc., can be added in Revit to use the MaterialConverterPrism Extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Prism" is an internal name for PBR (physically-based rendering) material system used by Forge Viewer. Not sure where exactly you've seen this, but I believe the viewer simply uses this internal implementation detail to take "non-Prism" materials from Revit designs, and update them so that they match the Prism system.